# how to prevent escaping of special characters in loop as argument for another command?

Tags: bash, shell

My input file (objects.lst) looks like this:

```
host.fqdn.com:/ 'host.fqdn.com [/]'
host.fqdn.com:/boot 'host.fqdn.com [/boot]'
host.fqdn.com:/tmp 'host.fqdn.com [/tmp]'
host.fqdn.com:/tmp '/tmp'
host.fqdn.com:/ '/usr/share'
host.fqdn.com:/var 'host.fqdn.com [/var]'
```

I want to loop over this file line by line and need every line as an argument for a 3rd party software.

So I tried something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
while read -r line; do
/opt/report -filesystem "$line" -detail
done < objects.lst
```

This will be interpreted as

```
 /opt/report -filesystem 'host.fqdn.com:/ '\''host.fqdn.com [/]'\''' -detail
```

But should be

```
/opt/report -filesystem host.fqdn.com:/ 'host.fqdn.com [/]'
```

I tried a lot of different things, like saving the argument in an array, `echo -E` into a variable, all kinds of different quotations and also via a for-loop, nothing worked the way I need it.

At the moment my workaround looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
while read -r line; do
echo "/opt/report -filesystem "${line}" -detail" | bash -
done < objects.lst
```

Is there another way to get this working without echoing/piping into bash - ?

I saw some examples with ${parameter@Q} (available with bash 4.4) but I'm on bash 4.2.

I obviously confused the set -x output, but my problem is still the same. I loop through the objects.lst and need the whole line exactly as it is in the objects.lst as an argument.

So if I understand the comments below correctly:

```
while read -r line; do
/opt/report -filesystem "$line" -detail
done < objects.lst
```

Should be the exact same thing as:

```
/opt/report -filesystem host.fqdn.com:/ 'host.fqdn.com [/]'
```

But it is not. Maybe the 3rd party software is the problem here (microfocus data protector / omnidb cli command) because in the loop, I get a "No Object Found" from omnidb/report.

But if I do a

```
while read -r line; do
echo "/opt/report -filesystem "$line" -detail"
done < objects.lst
```

And do a copy/paste from the output command, it works without a problem and prints the correct object information from the omnidb/report command.

Comment: The escapes aren't part of `$line` - they're just added for visualization when you use `set -x`. What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: If you need the arguments separated, you may be able use `read -r arg1 arg2`

Comment: @l0b0, actually, here it looks like the OP is confused, thinks they need to escape quotes but actually want them to be *interpreted* by the shell, so I wouldn't say it's a duplicate.

Comment: Note that the `-` in `bash -` is just an end-of-option marker, it doesn't mean _stdin_. `bash` alone is the same as `bash -`. `bash` like all shells read from stdin when not given any script to interpret on the command line.

Comment: I pass this arguments into a CLI tool from Microfocus to get backup statistics (omnidb). If i use the loop i always get an error that no backup objects with this name was found, if i echo "command" | bash - it works, also when i just echo the command and do a copy an paste.

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: [How to render variables without quotes in bash script?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/524935)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `/opt/report -filesystem "$line" -detail`, `host.fqdn.com:/ 'host.fqdn.com [/]'` is passed verbatim as *one* argument to the command and the `set -x` output is telling you just that by showing the value in single quotes which are the verbatim quotes in shells.

In

```
/opt/report -filesystem host.fqdn.com:/ 'host.fqdn.com [/]'
```

You're passing two arguments to the command: `host.fqdn.com:/` and `host.fqdn.com [/]`. That's be cause the space character and single quote characters are both special in the shell syntax.

For the shell, as seen above `'...'` are the *verbatim* quotes which serves at passing text literally without any character inside being treated specially, and SPC (when not itself quoted) in the shell syntax is used to separate arguments (or more generally, tokens in the shell syntax)

If you wanted to pass `host.fqdn.com:/ 'host.fqdn.com [/]'` literally as one argument, as shown by the `set -x` output, you'd need something like `'host.fqdn.com:/ '\''host.fqdn.com [/]'\'''`, though using other types of quotes like `"host.fqdn.com:/ 'host.fqdn.com [/]'"` would also work.

```
$ printf '<%s>\n' 'host.fqdn.com:/ '\''host.fqdn.com [/]'\'''
<host.fqdn.com:/ 'host.fqdn.com [/]'>
$ printf '<%s>\n' "host.fqdn.com:/ 'host.fqdn.com [/]'"
<host.fqdn.com:/ 'host.fqdn.com [/]'>
```

If you do actually need that `host.fqdn.com:/ 'host.fqdn.com [/]'` to be interpreted as shell code as opposed to being one literal argument to pass to the command, you would need to invoke the shell interpreter on the content of `$line` like with your piping to `bash` (though your usage of double quotes was incorrect) or `eval`:

```
#!/bin/bash -
set -x
while IFS= read -r line; do
  eval "/opt/report -filesystem $line -detail"
done < objects.lst
```

That means however that if a line contains `;reboot;` or `$(reboot)` for instance, that will invoke the `reboot` command.

If you only wanted to perform the shell tokenisation and quote removal without the other side effects like the running of those `reboot` commands above, you could use `zsh` instead which has operators for that:

```
#!/bin/zsh -
set -x
while IFS= read -r line; do
  /opt/report -filesystem "${(Q@)${(z)line}}" -detail
done < objects.lst
```

Where the `z` causes the tokenisation as `zsh` code, and `Q` removes one layer of quotes. For intance, on a line like:

```
foo 'bar baz' $(echo x y)
```

It would pass 3 arguments: `foo`, `bar baz` and `$(echo x y)`.

Comment: The eval example is exactly what i need and it works.
zsh is not available on my machines but i think the zsh approach is the same as the ${parameter@Q} in bash 4.4 right?

Comment: @T-One, no `${parameter@Q}` (a mksh operator recently added to `bash` while `zsh` had `(q)` decades before) is to *add* quoting, while here, you seem to be wanting to *interpret* (`(z)`) and *remove* (`(Q)`) quoting.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you write, it seems that you don't need the lines passed as single arguments to the program, but as two arguments: the unquoted part of the line as one, and the following quoted string as another.

**If** all those lines follow that format (and there aren't any lines with more quoted strings), you could do something like this in Bash:

```
#/bin/bash
while IFS=" " read -r a b; do
    b=${b%\'};
    b=${b#\'};
    /opt/report -filesystem "$a" "$b" -detail
done < objects.lst
```

The `read` splits the line in two on the first space, and stores the parts in `a` and `b`. Then `b=${b%\'}; b=${b#\'};` remove the single quotes, and then both strings are passed as distinct arguments to `/opt/report`.